# Uncaught type error: append is not a function

Tags: jquery

I want to create an array of 'people' and log them to the console.

**Here is my code :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function Person(firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        console.log('Person instantiated');
    }
    var people = new Array;
    people.append(new Person("Alice1"));
    people.append(new Person("Alice2"));
    people.append(new Person("Alice3"));
    people.append(new Person("Alice4"));

    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        console.log(people[i]);
    }
});
```

However, the console is spitting out this:

```
main.js:4 Person instantiated
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: people.append is not a function TypeError: people.append is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8383/p5/js/main.js:7:8)
    at j (http://localhost:8383/p5/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
    at k (http://localhost:8383/p5/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: people.append is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:7)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ main.js:7
j @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
```

I am initializing the `jquery.min.js` in the HTML file before my main js file, so what is causing this?

Comment: Because arrays do not have append.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: this has little to do with jquery - there error is a plain misunderstanding in how javascript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> TypeError: people.append is not a function

Mean that `append` isn't an **[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)** method, so you should use **[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** instead to add element to an array :

```
people.push(new Person("Alice1"));
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function Person(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    console.log('Person instantiated');
  }
  var people = new Array;
  people.push(new Person("Alice1"));
  people.push(new Person("Alice2"));
  people.push(new Person("Alice3"));
  people.push(new Person("Alice4"));

  for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    console.log(people[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```